# Wordpress call custom post save_post action from another function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have build a custom post in functions.php that works fine in the admin. Now I want to create a custom post manually from another php file using ajax. In functions.php I got something like this:

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_reference');

function save_reference(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "company", $_POST["company"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "contact", $_POST["contact"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "address", $_POST["address"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "zipcode", $_POST["zipcode"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "town", $_POST["town"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "phone", $_POST["phone"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "mobile", $_POST["mobile"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "email", $_POST["email"]);

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts
SET post_title = '$post->ID'
WHERE ID = $post->ID");

}
```

That one saves the post with the set post_metas and then updates the post title to be the actual post_id.

I have setup the ajax to work and I'm setting all $_POST values manually at this point. In my ajax (which is set lower in functions.php) I try call save_reference(); but nothing happens. I got something like this:

```
$_POST['company'] = $json_array2[0];
$_POST['contact'] = $json_array2[1];
$_POST['address'] = $json_array2[2];
$_POST['zipcode'] = $json_array2[3];
$_POST['town'] = $json_array2[4];
$_POST['phone'] = $json_array2[5];
$_POST['mobile'] = $json_array2[6];
$_POST['email'] = $json_array2[7];

$_POST['post_type'] = 'reference';
$_POST['content'] = 'test content';

save_reference();
```

I prefer not to save the data with wp_query as I want to be able to call the save_reference(); as it should do the trick. I tried something with wp_insert too but with no success. Please help me.

EDIT MY SOLUTION:
In the ajax I used:

```
global $post;
$post_ID = wp_insert_post(array('post_type' => 'reference', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_content' => "$_POST[content]"));
$post = get_post($post_ID);
save_reference();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the proper way to do this for a couple of reasons, but the main issue you have is that `$post` is not available in the AJAX context.

Comment: Yeah... I think I can just create an empty post and call the save_reference on that created $post... Anyways, you have any better idea how to create the custom post using the already existing function?

Comment: Not without some major changes - there are a couple of decently serious issues in both of your code samples. In the first, you don't want to update the `post_title` directly as this bypasses caching, filters, etc., but this also means you have to unhook and rehook to `save_post` to prevent a loop. In the second, you shouldn't be assigning values to the `$_POST`, and as I mentioned you don't have `$GLOBALS['post']` available.

Comment: PS - the "fix" you mentioned isn't exactly what I meant, it will likely cause you trouble. Give me a few and I will post an answer with the proper way to do it.

Comment: Please post your solution below as an answer, rather than within the question.  Please do not edit your title with "SOLVED", etc.

Comment: I change the title to the post id because this will only be used in admin as references and I want admin to be able to search the title as an "order nr".

Comment: I also put a solution in my post but it dissappeared... The query  $wpdb->query doesnt cause a loop by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The example below fixes a few issues with your example code. The issues:

- You are not properly handling post revisions
- You are bypassing the action and filter hooks by updating the `post_title` direction in the database
- Setting values to `$_POST` is generally frowned upon
- Using a keyed array instead of integer indexes will make getting your values easier, and allow your JSON to be swapped out for the `$_POST`.
- Only update the post when the title does not equal the ID since database updates are expensive.

Here is an example that aligns more with WordPress' recommendations.

```
// The save_post action will only pass in a $post_id, so we know it was AJAX if $json!=false
function save_reference( $post_id, $json=false ){
    //verify post is not a revision
    if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) 
        $post_id = $parent_id;

    // post we just saved
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    // only update the post if we need to since it's expensive
    if ( $post->post_title != $post_id ){
        // since we are going to update this post, we have to unhook to prevent a loop
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'save_reference' );

        // the data we want to update, set the post_title to the ID
        $update = array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $post_id,
        );
        wp_update_post( $update );

        // rehook since we DO want this method to be called if something else updates
        add_action( 'save_post', 'save_reference' );
    }

    // since we gave the $json key values we can use it in place of $_POST
    $input = ( $json )? $json : $_POST;

    update_post_meta( $post_id, "company", $input["company"] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "contact", $input["contact"] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "address", $input["address"] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "zipcode", $input["zipcode"] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "town", $input["town"] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "phone", $input["phone"] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "mobile", $input["mobile"] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, "email", $input["email"] );  
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_reference' );
```

And here is what the call to the `save_reference()` function would look like from your AJAX

```
// This could be done elsewhere if use a key instead if integer index for the array
$json = array(
    'company' => $json_array2[0],
    'contact' => $json_array2[1],
    'address' => $json_array2[2],
    'zipcode' => $json_array2[3],
    'town' => $json_array2[4],
    'phone' => $json_array2[5],
    'mobile' => $json_array2[6],
    'email' => $json_array2[7],
    'post_type' => 'reference', // not sure what this is for?
    'content' => 'test content', // not sure what this is for?
);
$post_id = // ??? you need to pass in a post_id with your AJAX call
save_reference( $post_id, $json );
```

Comment: To answer your mentioned issues, 1: What is post_revisions? 2: I update the title to the post_id as I handle it as an order_nr for display and search criteria in admin. I need to bypass the action hooks to prevent an infinite loop. 3: You are right on this one, The $_POST variable is already global as default in php, I had forgot that, thanks! 4: yeah, it can be swapped anyawys, I just collected all info in a jquery array and stringfy it before sending it to this ajax call. I do send json back to jquery with some parameters for json and it works fine. 5: yes, but i wanted to use same function